# using STL to find all elements in a vector

Tags: c++, stl

I have a collection of elements that I need to operate over, calling member functions on the collection:

```
std::vector<MyType> v;
... // vector is populated
```

For calling functions with no arguments it's pretty straight-forward:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mem_fun(&MyType::myfunc));
```

A similar thing can be done if there's one argument to the function I wish to call.

My problem is that I want to call a function on elements in the vector if it meets some condition.  `std::find_if` returns an iterator to the first element meeting the conditions of the predicate.

```
std::vector<MyType>::iterator it  = 
      std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), MyPred());
```

I wish to find **all** elements meeting the predicate and operate over them.

I've been looking at the STL algorithms for a "`find_all`" or "`do_if`" equivalent, or a way I can do this with the existing STL (such that I only need to iterate once), rather than rolling my own or simply do a standard iteration using a for loop and comparisons.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Boost Lambda makes this easy.

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/if.hpp>

std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), 
               if_( MyPred() )[ std::mem_fun(&MyType::myfunc) ] 
             );
```

You could even do away with defining MyPred(), if it is simple. This is where lambda really shines. E.g., if MyPred meant "is divisible by 2":

```
std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), 
               if_( _1 % 2 == 0 )[ std::mem_fun( &MyType::myfunc ) ]
             );
```

---

**Update:**
Doing this with the C++0x lambda syntax is also very nice (continuing with the predicate as modulo 2):

```
std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(),
               [](MyType& mt ) mutable
               {
                 if( mt % 2 == 0)
                 { 
                   mt.myfunc(); 
                 }
               } );
```

At first glance this looks like a step backwards from boost::lambda syntax, however, it is better because more complex functor logic is trivial to implement with c++0x syntax... where anything very complicated in boost::lambda gets tricky quickly. Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 currently implements this functionality.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a `for_each_if()` and a `for_each_equal()` which do what I think you're looking for.

`for_each_if()` takes a predicate functor to evaluate equality, and `for_each_equal()` takes a value of any type and does a direct comparison using `operator ==`.  In both cases, the function you pass in is called on each element that passes the equality test.

```
/* ---

    For each
    25.1.1

        template< class InputIterator, class Function, class T>
            Function for_each_equal(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value, Function f)

        template< class InputIterator, class Function, class Predicate >
            Function for_each_if(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred, Function f)

    Requires:   

        T is of type EqualityComparable (20.1.1) 

    Effects:    

         Applies f to each dereferenced iterator i in the range [first, last) where one of the following conditions hold:

            1:  *i == value
            2:  pred(*i) != false

    Returns:    

        f

    Complexity: 

        At most last - first applications of f

    --- */

    template< class InputIterator, class Function, class Predicate >
    Function for_each_if(InputIterator first, 
                         InputIterator last, 
                         Predicate pred, 
                         Function f)
    {
        for( ; first != last; ++first)
        {
            if( pred(*first) )
                f(*first);
        }
        return f;
    };

    template< class InputIterator, class Function, class T>
    Function for_each_equal(InputIterator first, 
                            InputIterator last, 
                            const T& value, 
                            Function f)
    {
        for( ; first != last; ++first)
        {
            if( *first == value )
                f(*first);
        }
        return f;
    };
```

Comment: +1 for posting working code that does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  Wow, this was an oldie!

Answer (score 6):

Is it ok to change the vector? You may want to look at the partition algorithm.

[Partition algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition.html)

Another option would be to change your `MyType::myfunc` to either check the element, or to take a predicate as a parameter and use it to test the element it's operating on.

Comment: Partitioning would work in a general case but for this specific case it will not work, as the vector cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int> v, matches;
std::vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin();
MyPred my_pred;
while(true) {
    i = std::find_if(i, v.end(), my_pred);
    if (i == v.end())
        break;
    matches.push_back(*i);
}
```

For the record, while I have seen an implementation where calling `end()` on a `list` was O(n), I haven't seen any STL implementations where calling `end()` on a `vector` was anything other than O(1) -- mainly because `vector`s are guaranteed to have random-access iterators.

Even so, if you are worried about an inefficient `end()`, you can use this code:

```
std::vector<int> v, matches;
std::vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(), end = v.end();
MyPred my_pred;
while(true) {
    i = std::find_if(i, v.end(), my_pred);
    if (i == end)
        break;
    matches.push_back(*i);
}
```

Comment: You could half the complexity of this loop by finding_if from i to v.end().  It remains quadratic, though... -1

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error in the original code.  The code up now is O(n):  start from the beginning -> find first match and store it -> starting from that position, find the next match and store it -> continue until you arrive at the end.

Comment: Won't this code add the first element of *v* to *matches*, regardless of *MyPred*?

Comment: The whole point of the for_each algorithm in the original question is to avoid an explicit loop. Your code just introduces the loop, which is obviously not an answer to the original question. -1.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth [for_each_if](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/cgi-bin/boost_wiki/wiki.pl?STLAlgorithmExtensions/ForEachIf) is being considered as an eventual addition to boost. It isn't hard to implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

Lamda functions - the idea is to do something like this

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](MyType& x){ if (Check(x) DoSuff(x); })
```

Origial post [here](http://softwareramblings.com/2008/04/c-lambda-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/foreach.html):

```
BOOST_FOREACH (vector<...>& x, v)
{
    if (Check(x)
        DoStuff(x);
}
```

Comment: I can use a traditional for loop as well.  This doesn't address the problem of wanting to use STL algorithms to write a cleaner version of the for_each with a predicate.  Lamdba's solve this problem quite elegantly.