# Find index range of specific values in sorted vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl, containers

I have a sorted `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` of x,y,z values as shown below,

```
0.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.1
0.0, 0.0, 0.2
0.0, 0.1, 0.0
0.0, 0.2, 0.1
0.0, 0.2, 0.3
```

I want to find all z values of a specific x and y value,
ex - z values of  0.0, 0.0, should return

```
0.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.1
0.0, 0.0, 0.2
```

I tried using

```
struct MatchDouble
{

    MatchDouble(double _x,double  _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
    bool operator()(std::vector<double> &n)
    {
        return fabs(x - n[0]) < FLT_EPSILON && fabs(y - n[1]) < FLT_EPSILON;

    }
private:
    double x, y ;
};

it = find_if(allpoints.begin(), allpoints.end(),MatchDouble(0.0,0.0));
```

But this only gives me the iterator to a single vector value. What method is best suited to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using STL to find all elements in a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234482/using-stl-to-find-all-elements-in-a-vector)

Comment: You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/234556/4074081) simple `for_each_if` wrapper if you don't want to make elements copies or check other answers there whether they suit your requirements better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> ret;
std::copy_if(allpoints.begin(), allpoints.end(), std::back_inserter(ret), MatchDouble(0.0,0.0));
return ret;
```

This creates a new `vector` ret of the same type as `allpoints` and copy only the points of interest using `copy_if`